# Simple? geometry question

Tags: geometry

My geometry is apparently more rusty then I thought. I am trying to find analytic equations for the problem illustrated in the figure below.

(Note: alpha must be greater then 45 degrees, as a > 0).

A square of dimension "r" that is bisected by a rhomboid of height "a".

[image]

============

Thank you Aretino for working out a solution!

For those of you who might be interested, this problem arose during a carpentry project: the construction of a shed door.

[image]

Yes, I know that there are simple ways to cut a board for the diagonal braces then deriving the formula. Curiousity was the motivation to seek an analytical solution. Curiousity that turned into a mild obsession.

Thanks again.

Comment: Hint:  for $h$, look at the small right triangle with hypotenuse $h$ and leg $a$.  One angle of that is $\alpha$.

Comment: Well, show us the rusty version of your geometry. Also, choose a more useful title.

Comment: The outer boundary is a diagonally cut square whose  vertical dimension is  increased by  adding $ a\sin  \alpha$ Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compute $h$ by equating the area of the square with the sum of the areas of the two triangles and the parallelogram:
$$
r^2=r(r-h)+a\sqrt{r^2+(r-h)^2}.
$$
By rearranging and squaring one gets:
$$
h=ar{\sqrt{2r^2-a^2}-a\over r^2-a^2}.
$$
From that you can easily compute $k=\sqrt{r^2+(r-h)^2}$ and $\alpha=\arcsin(r/k)$.

Comment: I rejected the proposed changes: it is obvious that I only took into account the positive solution for $h$. As it is geometrically obvious that $r\ge a$. Intelligenti pauca.

Comment: You still have to remove the square from the last $a$ in the numerator of the expression for $h$, though.

Comment: @1524 Right, thank you.

Comment: Thank you Aretino. Good work.

Comment: For those who are curious, this geometry problem comes from a carpentry project - the construction of a shed door:

Answer (score 0):

we have the following equations
$$r^2+(r-h)^2=k^2$$
$$\cos(\alpha)=\frac{r-h}{k}$$
$$\sin(\alpha)=\frac{a}{x}$$
$$\tan(\alpha)=\frac{x-r}{r}$$

Comment: Thank you Dr. Graubner. I assume that you meant "h" rather then "x" in the last two equations. Although, the last equation would seem to be off by a sign and should be r-h/r. I should have been more specific: I am looking for closed form analytical solutions for h, k and alpha.

Comment: i mean the little right angled triangle with the leg $a$ and the hypotenuse is my $x$

Comment: The hypotenuse is h.

Comment: ok then you can set $$x=h$$

Comment: Yes, I can. Still looking for a closed analytic expression for any of the three variables.

Answer (score 0):

The outer boundary is a diagonally cut square whose  vertical dimension is  increased by  adding $ a/ \sin  \alpha$.. right?$  \alpha=\pi/4$.  So you are just  adding a strip measuring $( r \cdot 
a/ \sin  \alpha)$ on top of square $ (r \cdot r )$.

Comment: α is not π/4. if it was, both diagonals would bisect both corners of the square